# no jdk found when opening pycharm?

Tags: java, pycharm

i have installed `pycharm` but when i want to open it this error occurs.

```
No JDK found. Please validate either PYCHARM_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME environment variable points to valid JDK installation.
```

but i have installed java.

output of `echo $JAVA_HOME` is `/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_74/`.

output of `echo $PATH` is `/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_74//bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`.

what can i do?

Comment: Have you set either of PYCHARM_JDK or JDK_HOME?  Have exported JAVA_HOME?  Is it set in the environment context in which `pycharm` executes?

Comment: i have exported JAVA_HOME, JDK_HOME and PYCHARM_JDK but it did not work

Answer (score 2):

In my case helps

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
export PYCHARM_JDK="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
```

in .zshrc or in .bashrc file.

`JAVA_HOME` used to be enough, but after the update it started to work only after adding `PYCHARM_JDK`.